# Accessing 3270 session via Python which is opened via Host on Demand

Tags: python-3.x, 3270

I am trying to access 3270 session via python. The session is available via host on demand so there is no config file available for me to access to.

```
from p3270 import P3270Client
myclient = P3270Client('sand.mf.com')
```

I tried something like this entering the server location and it did not work

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

is the error i get.

Any suggestions how to access it would be really helpful.

Regards,
Ren.

Answer (score 0):

The p3270 package relies on the s3270 utility. So it is required to have the s3270 installed on your system and available on your PATH. You can download it from http://x3270.bgp.nu/download.html. The p3270 supports only Linux so even if you install ws3270.exe it will not work. The following library works well on Windows: https://github.com/py3270

Comment: I tried it and added the path as well i get the error wc3270 not found